# Cant accept terms and conditions on PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I searched like a lot, but I cant accept terms and conditions on JetBrains PyCharm!

[image]

Comment: did you go to the bottom of the box ?

Comment: Clearly you didn't read all the terms and conditions.

Comment: You know what happens to people that don't read right? They get locked up at Apple HQ and are subjected to horrible experiments.

Comment: On some Gnome environments on Ubuntu it's buch harder. That checkbox...

Answer (score 14):

I had another related problem, in my case they added a checkbox, which was completely invisible on my system (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS):

[image: invisible checkbox in PuCharm User Agreement]

Comment: Really thankful! I was equally lost of what could be wrong with this button!

Comment: Invisible Checkbox FTW. :) Had this in Debian Stretch / KDE / OpenJDK8.

Answer (score 4):

Just scroll down the User Agreement to the very bottom -- the "Accept" button will become enabled then.

As simple as that. It even says that right on your screenshot.

[image]